# How to request extended permission from a facebook fan page tab

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am trying to request permission to publish photos from a facebook fan page tab(iframe).

I am calling **Facebook.showPermissionDialog('publish_stream');** before the upload(which doesn't seem to do much)

But I keep on getting this error when I try to upload a photo

```
**caught exception 'FacebookRestClientException' with message 'Permissions error'**
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the permissions aren't set.
Had problems with this myself, but found a solution, maybe it's helpful for you: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366709/more-settings-for-the-facebook-php-api)

Answer (score 0):

Get extended permission from user.[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524716/extended-permission-using-php-sdk/4635532#4635532)