# extended permission using php sdk

Tags: facebook

I am developing a facebook application using php-sdk. i want to take some extended permissions from user of my application. As this is application where user comes after login into facebook, so how can i take extended permission when user visit my page? We cannot place login button in which we can take permissions.I means when user first time comes to my application a pop up widow having a list of permission. How to display that at first visit of any user to my application. Any one can guide me how to take and where to place that code?
Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Awais Qarni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this

```
`<?php 
$app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
$app_sec = "APP_SEC";
$canvas_page = "APP_CANVAS_PAGE_URL";
$scope = "&scope=user_photos,email,publish_stream";   $auth_url"http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" .   urlencode($canvas_page).$scope; 
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];   
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode(".", $signed_request, 2); 
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, "-_", "+/")), true); 
 if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
 echo(""); } 
 $access_token = $data["oauth_token"]; 
$user_id = $data["user_id"]; 
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents( "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" .         $access_token)); 
function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret) { 
$args = array();
parse_str(trim($COOKIE["fbs" . $app_id], "\""), $args); 
ksort($args);
$payload = ""; 
foreach ($args as $key => $value) { 
if ($key != "sig") { 
$payload .= $key . "=" . $value; 
} 
} 
if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args["sig"]) {
return null; 
} 
return $args; 
} 
$cookie = get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_sec); 
?>
```